# Specify rails_env for rake to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two instances of a rails application on my AWS: Test and production

Anyways, so I have two seperate instances. The problem is when I run `rake db:migrate` for my production server, it runs the migrations (and console) for the production server. Ofcourse I mitigate this by using: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` but most of the times I forget the last part resulting in me running the migrations on the production server.

This can sometimes mess up the production environment as I am not ready to release them to production yet. So my question is: "Is there a way of specifying the environment for rake in the code, or somewhere in the apps directory, instead of typing it each time?"

Comment: sure, you can specify it in your code, but that would make it worse, you would have to change it once you push to production. the best thing to do is use environments variables, that you set on your remote server `export RAILS_ENV='staging'`

Comment: hmmm.. the problem is that I have the production environment in the same server. Is there anyway of ensuring that when it enters the test directory, the environment automatically changes to test and when it goes to production, the environment variable is automatically set.  I know it sounds futuristic, but it would be really convinient

Comment: use different users and apply the environment variable by user

Comment: btw, it's a pretty bad idea having both on the same "server" you should separate them at least virtually

Comment: It is, but I like to test on the same server before pushing to production. Then there's the fact that I am broke :(

Comment: when you are broke, you should use heroku, it's free

Comment: not a big fan of heroku. I like the power of shell access. I am a power whore, you could say

Comment: i don't think that you will come far with that approach (and stay broke)